# External library in Android

Tags: android

i was wondering if it's good to use external libraries took from git hub and use it in a professional app.This libraries may produce low performance or lag? Big company use external libraries for own apps?

Comment: You can check Instagram's Open Source Libraries section for that, If such a big company can use then why not others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Big Companies do use external libraries and sometimes they have enough resources or coders to create their own library .
External libraries doesn't usually creates lag in the app, infact some are really good and could enhance your app as well increase its performance.
some of the external libraries in github are open and many coders go through the code making it more efficient than a group of coders in a company creating a library. hence i would suggest you to review the libraries you want to use  and then if its having a positive review go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very common for both large and small companies to use external libraries. What libraries will usually depend on the license attached to them. As with any library there are both pro's and con's, both of which should be considered before you decide to use one.